# plotting multiple charts using facet grid

Tags: r, plot, facet-grid

I'm working on a time series of different stocks, and I am getting some issues in plotting them efficiently.

So my dataset looks like this:

```
              A       B       C       D
1/2/2012    0.007   0.012   0.015   0.009
1/3/2012    0.009   0.012   0.015   0.008
1/4/2012    0.012   0.012   0.015   0.009
1/5/2012    0.013   0.012   0.015   0.012
1/6/2012    0.013   0.012   0.015   0.011
1/9/2012    0.013   0.012   0.015   0.011
1/10/2012   0.013   0.009   0.015   0.011
1/11/2012   0.013   0.009   0.015   0.014
1/12/2012   0.013   0.009   0.015   0.014
1/13/2012   0.013   0.009   0.015   0.013
1/16/2012   0.013   0.012   0.014   0.017
1/17/2012   0.013   0.013   0.015   0.017
1/18/2012   0.014   0.013   0.015   0.018
1/19/2012   0.014   0.013   0.015   0.018
1/20/2012   0.015   0.012   0.015   0.018
1/24/2012   0.016   0.011   0.016   0.018
1/25/2012   0.016   0.011   0.016   0.019
1/26/2012   0.016   0.010   0.015   0.021
1/27/2012   0.016   0.010   0.015   0.022
1/30/2012   0.016   0.010   0.015   0.022
1/31/2012   0.016   0.010   0.015   0.022
2/1/2012    0.016   0.010   0.015   0.022
2/2/2012    0.020   0.012   0.015   0.025
```

Right now, I plotted all of the manually `gX <- ggplot(dat, aes(Index, X)) + geom_line` and plotted them together through `grid.arrange(g1, g2, g3, g4)`

Is there a way to plot these using facet_grid since the way I did it was inefficient and rigid?

Below is the plot I did manually:

[image]

Comment: What are the `Index` and `X` column

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for facet_grid? You simply need a grouping variable for each of your data 'subsets'; I'm guessing in your case this is things like AC and AEV? Then you just call `facet_grid(~groupingVariable)`.

Comment: `facet_wrap` would be a better choice, as there appears to be only a single grouping variable: `facet_wrap(~stock, ncol=5, scales='free_y')` could produce something similar, but the name of the stock would be on top of each panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming in your data.frame `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` are stock names, you must first create a long-table of the following form:

```
Date       Stock   value
1/2/2012   A       0.007
1/2/2012   B       0.012
1/2/2012   C       0.015
1/2/2012   D       0.009
1/3/2012   A       0.009
1/3/2012   A       0.012
1/3/2012   A       0.015
1/3/2012   A       0.008
```

I'll assume your first column is rownames, and that will have to be imported as a column into your data frame. Then use `gather` from `tidyr` to create the data frame in long-format.

```
library(tidyr)
df$Date <- rownames(df)
long <- gather(df, Stock, value, -Date)
ggplot(aes(x=Date, y=Value)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~Stock, scales='free_y', ncol=5)
```

In `gather`, first argument the 2nd argument is the name of the column that will contain the earlier column names, and the 3rd argument is the name of the column that will contain their values. The following arguments to `gather` are to select which columns to gather, in this case it is all *except*  `Date` (since you have many and wouldn't want to bother typing them all manually).

Comment: Thanks MrGumble, I wasn't aware that I have to convert my data into long-table first to use facets!

Comment: You're welcome. For ggplot2, the starting point is generally to have your data in long-table format: 1 column, 1 variable. All x-values in the same column, all y-axes in the same column, all variables for colour in the same column, etc. Of course, at some point, you'll have to deviate from this.

Comment: trelliscopejs is a great package for displaying multiple plots with interactivity, the ability to filter and sort once produced as a whole. https://hafen.github.io/trelliscopejs/articles/trelliscopejs.html